# Trackpad randomly dies

Tags: mouse, macbook, macbook-pro, trackpad

My Macbook's trackpad will randomly stop working (frequency seems to be every couple weeks) and the only way I've found to fix it is to reboot. I'd file a bug report, but I'm not sure what component I'd be reporting about. Is there any way to prevent this or fix it without a reboot? Everything else still seems to work fine, so I'm assuming some mouse-driver is crashing and not being restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having problems on my MacBook as well (particularly since upgrading to 14.10).  When the trackpad freezes, I can get it working again with:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

I still haven't figured out how to turn off the trackpad while typing (even with System Settings -> Mouse & Trackpad -> Touchpad disable while typing box checked; and `synclient PalmDetect=1`).

The trackpad also seems to zoom in/out in an application when accidentally brushed.

Comment: It just happened again, and I tried this and it had no effect.

Comment: to turn off the trackpad while typing use: `synclient TouchpadOff=2`

Comment: Hmm...I guess I should have (first) suggested checking the status with synclient -l | grep Touchpad

Comment: (first comment got cut off)..maybe a driver issue?  Here is a dated post (and Ubuntu 12.10) but maybe info is useful http://www.chris-reilly.org/blog/technotes/macbook-trackpad-in-ubuntu/